# Using while(true) in application_start event in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, global-asax

There's particular situation that I need to use `while(true)` in application_start event to monitor a queue.

Does it cost the most performance of IIS? Or does it raise a cpu overload event or other bad effect?

That's my question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That is not a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you want to do actually?

Comment: This is not a good idea as your application would not start. Why not starting a background thread (with or without timer) if you want to monitor something?

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I will use Task to accomplish the while(true)